# How can I pass a List View set /array of RecordIds using a custom button to Apex Class

Tags: apex, custom-button, onclickjavascript

I am newbie. I'm trying to pass in a List of recordids through the use of a custom button from a List View in classic. The parameters section of the sforce.apex.execute method is not right.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/50.0/connection.js")}

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/50.0/apex.js")}

var ids = {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Request__c )};

sforce.apex.execute("UpdateWireStatus","getWireDetails",{ids});   <<<---??

window.location.reload();
```

**Here is the Apex Class that will receive the List of Ids.**

```
 global class UpdateWireStatus {

 @TestVisible
private static Boolean testException = false;

webService static void getWireDetails( List<Id'> requestIdList) {
            
System.debug('ID:' + requestIdList);
           
 List<Request__c> requestRecordList = PershingHelper.getRequestRecords(requestIdList);

            for (Request__c thisRequest : requestRecordList) {
                Pershing.getWireDetails(thisRequest);
            }

            try {
                if(testException) {
                    throw  new RTSCallout.ApiException('Test Exception');
                }
                Database.update(requestRecordList, false);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug('Error updating Request: ' + e.getMessage() + ':' + e.getStackTraceString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try doing `{"ids": ids}` instead of just `{ids}`

Comment: @fred `{ "ids": ids }` and `{ids}` are identical.

Comment: @sfdcfox I know but isn't that quite a recent change? I thought maybe since it's a classic Javascript button it might not be valid syntax? Happy to be corrected!

Comment: @fred This syntax came out with ES6, around 2015. Classic buttons use whatever JavaScript is supported by the browser, and all Salesforce-supported browsers are new enough to support this.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter names have to match:

```
webService static void getWireDetails( List<Id> requestIdList) {
```

...

```
var requestIdList = {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Request__c )};
sforce.apex.execute("UpdateWireStatus","getWireDetails",{requestIdList});
```

Note that this is case sensitive.